# jQuery positioning bug in one link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to create a menu panel with jQuery that can be seen here by clicking the **Preview** button on top:

```
$(function(){
  // hide all panels first
  $('div[id*="panel"]').hide();
  
  // make the panels absolute positioned
  $('div[id*="panel"]').css('position', 'absolute');
  
  // show the panel based on rel attribute of the current hovered link
  $('#menu a').hover(function(){
    var link_rel = $(this).attr('rel');

    //get the position of the hovered element
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    
    // set z-index of previous panels low
    $('div[id*="panel"]').css('z-index', '0');
    
    // get the panel near by hovered element now
    $('div#' + link_rel).css({
      'left': pos.left + 'px',
      'top': pos.top + 'px',
      'zIndex': '5000'
    });
    
    // finaly show the relevant hidden panel
    $('div#' + link_rel).fadeIn('slow');

    // hide it back when mouse arrow moves away
    $('div#' + link_rel).hover(function(){}, function(){
      $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });

  }, function(){});
  
});
```

http://jsbin.com/amexi/edit

If you hover over **Link Two** or **Link Three**, the black panel comes perfectly replacing the respective blue link, however if you hover the **Link One**, the black panel comes little below that link. What's wrong here? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to account for the margin automatically applied to `<ul>` elements.

If you look at your page with Firebug, you'll notice Firefox applies a top and bottom margin of 16px.

Comment: Correct!

Add this to your CSS:

ul {padding:0;margin:0}

Comment: @Jer: Thanks i also zero out but forgot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, you can apply a margin-top value of -16px to the .left class to get your intended behaviour.

http://jsbin.com/amexi/3/edit

Comment: Margin values are not relative to their current value. Setting the top margin to 0 would be the correct solution.

Comment: Yes, as Jer said adding ul {padding:0;margin:0;} (below the 'ul#menu li a' rule)  is the the correct solution.

Comment: To avoid stuff like this I usually zero out margins and padding at the top of my stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://jsbin.com/amexi/5/edit

I just can't figure out why the TOP is identical on all the popups BUT the actual position of them all is different. Makes no sense. Its almost like a negative margin.

The main problem I found is that you didnt move the popup into the position of the link + offset it to the .top + .height.